# Remote modal on drop down select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open a bootstrap modal from the last option select of a drop down list. I can make it show but cannot input the content from remote.

**javascript**

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
  var opval = $(this).val();
  if (opval == "showModal") {
    $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('data-remote'));
  }
});
```

Please see fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/m6umwc6n/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the remote attribute is in the selected option. you need to add `.find("option:selected")`  :

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
  var opval = $(this).val();
  if (opval == "showModal") {
    $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-remote'));
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1fkxx591/